# Shell Script executing Oracle PL/SQL code

Tags: shell, plsql

I'm calling a PL/SQL code from shell script which takes time to finish, but after completion of PL/SQL code the shell script session is not terminated and also still shows as active when is type `ps -aef|grep 'SQL*PLUS'`.  Any suggestion why the shell script session is not terminated.

Note : PL/SQL code has no issue and ran successfully. I have used cron job to run the shell script.

The shell script is terminated when Data is less to process.

Comment: You forgot to exit SQL*Plus in your shell script?

Comment: @Abra  I have terminated the shell script properly.

Comment: If you really want me to help you, please [edit] your question and post your script that you claim to be having problems with. Also, please excuse my ignorance, but how does one terminate a shell script properly?